# Is there someway to make a scalable frame or nine-patch within inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I don't mean that I want to create nine-patch pngs for use somewhere else.

I'd like to create text-frames with corner ornaments that are not scaled in either direction when the whole frame is scaled, i.e. something like a nine-patch for use *within* Inkscape.

A nine-patch is a scalable frame divided into nine pieces in a 3x3 grid (like a game of noughts and crosses).  Some ornamental frame is drawn in the eight outer cells of the grid, while the center cell contains the content.  When a nine-patch is scaled only the central content cell changes size.  The outer cells remain the same scale and the "frame" is not distorted.

The reason I'd like nine-patches in inkscape is that it would allow me to create flowcharts I can share with people (with lots of nine-patch frames).  Ideally they would be able to scale the frames without getting too involved in the art side and layout.

Comment: Two quick points: 1) you may need to explain to folks what you mean by a nine-patch - not everyone here has been involved in Android OS development; 2) InkScape is a vector art tool, and so everything it creates is inherently rescalable in terms of internal uses, so no need to develop a nine-patch at all just for internal in-inkscape use.

Comment: @GerardFalla valid criticism.. I've expanded the question to reflect your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a border with corner ornaments, you can use the Edit Paths by Nodes tool (F2) to select one side of the border then move it with the arrow keys.

For example

[image]

Comment: Yeah.  Nice answer.  It's not ideal but I suspect it's the only option.  Ideally, I'd like to scale the frames using the normal scaling approach.  I was looking at the extension mechanisms and I suspect they're not capable of creating a frame like this.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog - if you want you can hold down Shift as you use the arrow keys to move in bigger steps.